# PHP datetime returned from mysql is wrong

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, nginx, ubuntu-16.04

I am getting this weird behavior when fetching a datetime column from mysql table.

Here is the scenario:

There's a datetime column in **notifications** table where the date and time stored is correct.

But when I query the db from php, I get the wrong time (UTC + 0:00 which is supposed to UTC - 05:00)
My system timezone is UTC - 05:00.

Even PHP's date function returns the correct date and time.

I have attached 3 images below showing time from the server, MySQL and PHP (with the issue)

I changed the system timezone, mysql timezone and php timezone but still the issue persists.

The server is nginx with php 7.0 on an ubuntu machine.

Please help me fix the issue.
[image: Mysql notifications table][image: Server time][image: PHP date with issue]

Comment: Are you positive the timezone is set exactly for both php and mysql? Don't rely on system time, whats the configs set too?

Comment: php and system are both America/New_York and mysql is utc-5:00

Comment: make sure that both php and mysql server have the same timezone, this is a timezone issue not a php or sql query  issue

Comment: Are you sure the replied_on field is a datetime and not a timestamp, which are always UTC?

Comment: Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are hostile to those who use screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. Use the `{}` button to format any blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. **We can’t run your screenshot as code.** Your screenshots are a total mess, and that redaction is really not effective anyway.

Comment: If you want to permanently eliminate these and other headaches set every timezone [OS/mysql/etc] to UTC, store and compute exclusively in UTC, and only convert to non-UTC for display.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Well It was timestamp defaulting to current_timestamp. I changed it to datetime and it worked. Weird how timestamp works. anyway thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Timezones are one of the most annoying things you can deal with in a system.  As a rule of thumb, I ALWAYS make sure all servers/containers/configs/etc... are all set to UTC and save UTC into the database.  If you need to display something else, you can store the account/user timezone in the database and transform it before displaying the information.

It is amazing how many projects I have come into that use PST/PDT as a timezone and it causes HUGE issues down the line.

Also, I would recommend using Carbon as a helper lib for DateTime object in PHP.  https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon